# Adding picture in write latex

Tags: graphics, formatting

I have been using kile as latex editor but I found some errors and couldn't overcome with that so I i am trying to compile my tex file in [write-latex](https://www.writelatex.com/1989561svmvxp#/5009827/).
But the online editor is showing that picture is missing. How can i add picture in the writelatex?

https://www.writelatex.com/1989561svmvxp#/5009827/

Comment: This makes no sense. The only reason this might help is if your installation of TeX uses a different version of a package or whatever from the online installation, and that difference is responsible for the errors. This is certainly possible but statistically less likely than that your code has errors which cause errors when you try to compile it. Either way, Kile has nothing to do with it. It is just an editor.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to "Project" and upload the missing files via the "Add files…" button, since the files have to be on the server, that is running writeLaTeX.

In this case the file has to be named `picture.<file-ext>`, as this part of the code implies:

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
```

If you don't want a photo, you can also just comment out this line (it's line `63`) by putting an `%` in front of it.

[image]

As you can see, `frog.jpg` from the example file is already there.